# What is wrong with this? It keeps telling me: too many arguments for format -wformat-extra-args

Tags: c

I am new at this and I have no idea why it is not working.  I can run it but it won't calculate a thing.  I'm using C and I already placed the `#include <math.h>`

```
printf("X1 es igual a:\n", (-b+sqrt(R))/(2*a));
printf("X2 es igual a:\n", -b/(2*a),(sqrt(-R))/(2*a));
```

Comment: Oscar Ozuna, Tip, avoid "and I have no idea why it is not working" and instead post a [mcve].  Sample input, outputs seen, outputs expected help too.  Rather than "but it won't calculate a thing", post what it did - even if the result was "an empty output".

Comment: how can it know what you are going to print?

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` arguments need matching specifiers.

```
// printf("X1 es igual a:\n", (-b+sqrt(R))/(2*a));
printf("X1 es igual a:%g\n", (-b+sqrt(R))/(2*a)); 
//                    ^^---- specifier for a double
```

---

Unless `R==0`, `sqrt(R)` or `sqrt(-R)` will cause problems.  Add a test.

```
if (a) {
  if (R >= 0) printf("X1 es igual a:%g\n", (-b+sqrt(R))/(2*a));
  if (R <= 0) printf("X2 es igual a:%g i*%g\n", -b/(2*a),(sqrt(-R))/(2*a));
}
```